# Cannot find module 'ansi-regex' | npm not getting uninstalled or updated

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, npm-install

I am unable to uninstall or update npm. I tried running `rn -rf node-modules`, `rimraf node-modules`, and even manually deleting the npm folder from the system. I even removed the environment variable. Unfortunately, nothing is working.

I uninstalled nodejs and completely removed **ALL** the folders and temp files. Post system restart, I did a fresh installation of nodejs and when I again tried to install npm, I get this error:

```
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'ansi-regex'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\n
ode_modules\strip-ansi\index.js:2:38)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Basically, whatever method I tried, I get the same error. Please help!

**node version: v6.11.0**

**OS: Windows 8**

I have also tried installing 'ansi-regex' using `npm install ansi-regex`

Comment: did u ever find a solution for this ? ansi-regex is installed in my project but still getting error.

Comment: Have you tried `npm install -g npm`?